# Unsupported operand type method + method

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror

I've actually already found a work around for my problem, but I feel as though there is still a better way. I can't seem to grasp why the program thinks I'm dealing with a **method** vs a **float**.

If I try to run the program, it says that I'm trying to add together two **methods**. However, when I run the line:

`print(type(my.coins.add_coins()))`

It tells me that it has returned a **float**.

Here's the code:

```
class Currency:
    def __init__(self, pennies, nickles, dimes, quarters):
        self.pennies = pennies
        self.nickles = nickles
        self.dimes = dimes
        self.quarters = quarters

    def penny_value(self):
        return self.pennies * .01

    def nickle_value(self):
        return self.nickles * .05

    def dime_value(self):
        return self.dimes * .1

    def quarter_value(self):
        return self.quarters * .25

    def add_coins(self):
        return self.penny_value + self.nickle_value + self.dime_value + self.quarter_value

my_coins = Currency(1, 1, 1, 1)



#why does this work?
print(my_coins.penny_value() + my_coins.nickle_value())

#but not this?
print(my_coins.add_coins())
```

Comment: `penny_value` is not `penny_value()`…

Comment: Jesus.... I feel dumb. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are summing functions; Here is what you want to do:

```
def add_coins(self):
    return self.penny_value() + self.nickle_value() + self.dime_value() + self.quarter_value()
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel dumb for that. But I appreciate the help!